# Intall QScintilla2 for Eric IDE for python3

Tags: python3, eric

I try to execute the following command with. But it is giving error. How can I overcome that

command : `python3 install.py`

error :

```
Checking dependencies
Python Version: 3.5.2
Found PyQt5
Found pyuic5
Sorry, please install QScintilla2 and
its PyQt5/PyQt4 wrapper.
Error: cannot import name 'Qsci'
```

Please help.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-qscintilla2`

Comment: @Raphael I suspect that qscintilla2 install with python 2.7.12 but not with python3

Comment: I am getting an error with @Raphael's suggested command: `python-qscintilla2 : Depends: sip-api-11.2
`

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5.qsci` is what you need.